# Reverting a specific file to an earlier commit without affecting other files

Tags: git

I have a Git repository where I made changes to multiple files in the latest commit. However, I realize that I need to revert only one file to its state in a previous commit without affecting the changes in other files.

I've tried using git checkout  --  to revert the specific file, but I'm concerned that it might impact other changes I made in the latest commit. What's the safest way to revert only the changes in one file to a previous commit without altering the rest of the working directory?

Comment: If you provide the specific file, only that file is taken straight from that commit or branch you provide: `git checkout some-commit-or-branch -- some-file`. Also works with restore: `git restore --source some-commit-or-branch -- some-file`